# Vuejs not prompting bootstrap popover

Tags: vue.js

I am using `bootstrap popover` with `vuejs`.

How can I trigger `vue` functionality?

In below code when I am clicking on `add break` link, it opens `bootstrap popover`, with `click me` button. Now here `vuejs` doesn't work, if I click on `click me`, it is not prompting alert.

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"  v-d2d-popover  data-content='<button v-on:click="alert(6)">click me</button>' href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link popover-notitle">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus-circle bigger-120 green"></i>add break
</a>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: i'm having the same issue... the popover content is dynamically added to the DOM by Bootstrap... when that happens, the v-on directive is not automatically recognized by the vue instance, so it does not work... we need some way to tell vue to render the component again, but i haven't found a way to do that yet... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Since the button is just written in a string, it isn't being compiled by Vue. Here are a couple of ideas to try:

1. Use Vue for popover as well: https://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#popover
2. Create popover content in a separate div (in your component so Vue will compile it) and then fetch the content for the popover:

   `{
       content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
       html: true
   }`

Comment: The second approach works well for displaying-only components, while functionality like model/input binding will not work. The binding effect will happen in the div but not in the popover content.